# How to dynamically set the properties of child class inside the generic parent class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-generics

Suppose I have an abstract class that has the method setPropertiesToTrue that takes in a list of class properties from a child class, and sets those properties inside the child to true.

```
abstract class BaseObject<TBooleanProp extends string>{
  setPropertiesToTrue(properties: TBooleanProp[]){
    properties.forEach(property => {
      (this[property] as boolean) = true
    })
  } 
}

class SomeObject extends BaseObject<"x"| "y">{ 
  x: boolean ;
  y: boolean;
  z: string;
  

  constructor(x: boolean, y: boolean, z: string){
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}


const object = new SomeObject(false, false, "hello")

object.setPropertiesToTrue(["x", "y"])

// @ts-expect-error this should not be possible
object.setPropertiesToTrue(["z"])

console.log(object.x) // changed from false to true
console.log(object.y) // changed from false to true
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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) is a TS Playground example of more or less what I'm trying to do.

In the example above, I have no idea how to tell Typescript that the properties being passed into `setPropertiesToTrue` are boolean properties setup in the child constructor.

Hence, typescript is rightfully complaining at line 4. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: TS doesn't really allow class declarations to have dynamic property keys; you can use a type assertion to tell the compiler that a class has the right shape, though.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/weXrVW) meet your needs?  Note that nothing you do will stop `console.log(object.z)` from being `true` unless you actually remove the `object.setPropertiesToTrue(["z"])` line.  Can you please remove the expectation that `object.z` will be unchanged from your example?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's true. I updated my question. Could you walk me through your approach? especially the `as any as abstract new <K extends string>() => BaseObject<K>;` part? What exactly is going on there?

Comment: "I updated my question." I don't see that.  I can walk through the approach if I write up an answer; are you not sure if my solution meets your needs without having such an explanation in advance?

Comment: woops. should be good now. 

The fact that there is a ton of casting taking place makes me question whether I'm on the right path in terms of object-design. Sound like if I just define `setPropertiesToTrue` inside the child class saves me from a ton of headache.

But either way, I would love to read your answer. Looks like it can teach me a few things about Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) and [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) declarations must have *statically known keys*.  This means that the compiler must know their exact literal keys at the declaration site.  There are ways to represent types with dynamic/programmatic keys, such as in [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like `type Foo<K extends string> = {[P in K]: number}`.  The [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is probably the canonical example of a mapped type with a dynamic key.

So such types can be described and used, but the compiler will never allow or accept a `class` declaration to be of those types directly.  Instead, you can make  a `class` declaration that acts the way you want at runtime and give it whatever types the compiler needs to make it compile.  After this you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to say that that class is of the dynamic type you want.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
type BaseObject<K extends string> = Record<K, boolean> & {
  setPropertiesToTrue(properties: K[]): void;
}
const BaseObject = class BaseObject {
  [k: string]: any;
  setPropertiesToTrue(properties: string[]) {
    properties.forEach(property => {
      this[property] = true
    })
  }
} as any as abstract new <K extends string>() => BaseObject<K>;
```

So, the type `BaseObject<K>` describes the shape of an instance of the `BaseObject` class.  It is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `Record<K, boolean>` (a type with keys in `K` whose values are `boolean`) and `{setPropertiesToTrue(properties: K[]): void}` (a type with a single method accepting an array of `K` elements).

We assign a `class` expression to `BaseObject` which acts the way we want at runtime.  By giving it a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) whose value is of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), we've mostly turned off type checking inside the class body.

And finally, we assert that this class expression is of the type `abstract new <K extends string>() => BaseObject<K>`; that's an [`abstract` construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) which says that `BaseObject` is an abstract class constructor (so if you try to write `new BaseObject()` directly you'll get an error).  Without `abstract` it would just be a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).

It's also a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) constructor, so when you use the `new` operator, you specify a type parameter `K` and the resulting instance is of type `BaseObject<K>`.

This needs to be an assertion because the compiler can't see the class expression as meeting that dynamic thing.  It's unrelated enough according to the compiler that you need to use `as any as` or `as unknown as` to suppress the error.

---

Let's see if it works.

```
class SomeObject extends BaseObject<"x" | "y"> {
  z: string;
  constructor(x: boolean, y: boolean, z: string) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}

const object = new SomeObject(false, false, "hello")
object.setPropertiesToTrue(["x", "y"]) // okay
object.setPropertiesToTrue(["z"]) // error
// -----------------------> ~~~
// Type '"z"' is not assignable to type '"x" | "y"'.
```

Looks good!  The compiler sees `object` as having properties `x`, `y`, and `z`, and only lets you call `setPropertiesToTrue()` with arrays containing `"x"` and `"y"`; note that in `SomeObject` I didn't have to explicitly declare the `x` and `y` properties; these are inherited from `BaseObject<"x" | "y">`, which is good, since that's part of the point of `BaseObject`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgeQEYCsIGNgB4DSUEAHsBAHYAmCUCwATgJbkDmAfFALxQBK2A9vUoEANFFT9+AGwhxyHAGRQA3gCgotCMAAK9fpHrBGEBABV+p+gFcIACjB6DRkwC4o+ANoBdAJRuAbvyMlADcqgC+qlj85HSwiCgY2MBcUFhSiDTwSGiYOCrqUB4A1m50TKxebnIgYRpIOo4QhsZmFtZ2DvrNzghlDMws3j4FGhpdTq0AdABmggCicFgAFvZNhiBcHGpjY8DLjAgeEz0gXqkMNoUa4T6FkeFQiE-km89wqOVLKeQQAO5QAhEUgUai0AasNi2EacDjZRJ5PD4NhhVRRDIIGgAZX4AFsEclgWQqFkErlkrgAETESlQAA+UEpIEp20KAC9+hUWHU0jFylYcIJbMQ3BJpLJyGIQKLJDI5GIOeCuSMdmMEFYDNCeRp9ocpsRUsRtVBdQgpptuLVriaDma2ak2TyHmjorEUvwkvluL8ATj8eScLYZnApEgxMHQxAxJTlhApFJ+JS7qoPYipg1dN0WiZzJYbLYPNTKdHmb4oAB6ctQfjFOAgFOe4DprSZyY59r5wtsyllytEeh6eiqPsAWjH44nk6nY44AD958Oq6ZwNAAOSU7urqCHKDkfgpTKMFjkD4yE38E0rqDrmn0xnM1dTNFAA)